# Cygwin not compiling stod

Tags: c++, c++11, cygwin

I'm trying to compile this [example code](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/)

```
#include <iostream>   // std::cout
#include <string>     // std::string, std::stod

int main ()
{
  std::string orbits ("365.24 29.53");
  std::string::size_type sz;     // alias of size_t

  double earth = std::stod (orbits,&sz);
  double moon = std::stod (orbits.substr(sz));
  std::cout << "The moon completes " << (earth/moon) << " orbits per Earth year.\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Trying to compile from the command prompt gives

```
C:\Users\DWane\Documents>g++ -std=c++0x testme.cpp -o out.exe
testme.cpp: In function 'int main()':
testme.cpp:9:18: error: 'stod' is not a member of 'std'
   double earth = std::stod (orbits,&sz);
                  ^
testme.cpp:10:17: error: 'stod' is not a member of 'std'
   double moon = std::stod (orbits.substr(sz));
                 ^
```

I'm running Windows 8 64bit and have g++ (GCC) 4.8.3.

Comment: You probably have an old version of GCC. `stod` is a fairly recent addition to the library.

Comment: @MikeSeymour it's 4.8.3

Comment: But current GCC is 4.9.1 ...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Even so, 4.8 has more-or-less full support for C++11, and should include `stod`.

Comment: You said it yourself: "more or less". GCC is improving its C++11 compliance. On Debian/Linux/x86-64 with GCC 4.9.1 your example is compiling ok with `g++ -Wall -std=c++11`

Comment: It works on ubuntu with a GCC 4.6.3

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that it's a bug within Cygwin's port of GCC (or libstdc++). The only message I can find on the Cygwin mailing list is from [Jan 29, 2014](https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin/2014-01/msg00508.html) and it merely says:

> Did you try the suggestion for the same problem under mingw?  It looks
>   like this could be a temporary workaround  until the problem is fixed.
>   Just make
>
> sure you try it on
>   /lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h if
>   you're building for Cygwin..

MinGW has been known to have issues with string conversion functions as well, even though it's different from Cygwin. My suggestion is to download Stephan T. Lavavej's [64-bit MinGW distribution](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) which comes with GCC 4.9.1 and many up to date packages.