# Where do you call delete if you intended for variables to remain after going out of scope?

Tags: c++, dynamic, pthreads, new-operator

So say we have

```
struct Data
{
 int x;
 int y;
 int z;
}

void doWork()
{
  Data d;
  d.x = 1;
  d.y = 2;
  d.z = 3;
  pthread_t thrd;
  pthread_create(&thrd, NULL, someFunction, (void*)&d);
}

pthread_mutex_t outputLock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;//global scope

void* someFunction(void* arg)
{
  Data d = (Data*)arg;
  pthread_mutex_lock(&outputLock);
  std::cout << d->x->d->y+d->z;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&outputLock);
}
```

This causes undefined behaviour because as soon doWork() returns the argument to someFunction() becomes corrupt. To fix this I do

`Data* d = new Data();`
My question is, do I have to worry about memory leaks since I'm not calling `delete`? When the program ends, does it automatically clean up any memory leaks?

Sadly (as far as I'm aware) C++11 can't be developed on Windows 8 (because it seems Cygwin is very buggy with it).

Comment: `arg` is not a `Data`, it's a `Data*`. `Data` is probably bigger than `void*` and can't fit anyway. And I don't know what you're talking about in regards to C++11. It works fine on Windows 8.

Comment: In `someFunction()` you could place `d` into a smart pointer or make sure you `delete` it when the function returns. Then, in `doWork()` make `d` a `Data*` and create it using `new`. Pass that to the thread parameter.

Comment: @chris re windows 8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561919/cygwin-not-compiling-stod if you know how to get it to work do tell

Comment: Well I wouldn't be surprised if the MinGW fix works. I wouldn't know, though. I use Clang and MinGW.

Comment: Visual Studio compiles much of c++11 for Windows.

Answer (score 3):

**You could do this:**

```
struct Data
{
 int x;
 int y;
 int z;
}

void doWork()
{
  Data* dat = new Data;
  dat->x = 1;
  dat->y = 2;
  dat->z = 3;
  pthread_t thrd;
  if(pthread_create(&thrd, NULL, someFunction, (void*)dat) != 0)
      delete dat; // if thread not created need to cleanup here
}

void* someFunction(void* arg)
{
  Data* d = (Data*)arg;
  std::cout << d->x->d->y+d->z;
  delete d;
}
```

**Or** (better) **use a smart pointer:**

```
void* someFunction(void* arg)
{
    // From C++11 use std::unique_ptr
    std::auto_ptr<Data> d(reinterpret_cast<Data*>(arg)); // C++ style cast
    std::cout << d->x->d->y+d->z;
}
```

**NOTE:** `std::auto_ptr` is superseded by `std::unique_ptr` in C++11

Comment: I notice you use the identifier `d` in two places. When you call `delete d` which `d` is it refering to? If it's refering to the one in `someFunction()`'s scope, isn't there still a memory leak?

Comment: @Celeritas No memory leak. It is referring to the `d` defined in `someFunction()` and it gets deleted after `someFunction()` is done with it.

Comment: @remyabel because no C++11 in the question tag, but I'm about to add it as a better option.

Comment: @Galik "it is referring to the d defined in someFunction()" so isn't that a problem because `new` was called in doWork? Is it that both variables point to the same address?

Comment: @Celeritas No because all `delete` cares about is the *value* of the pointer. That *value* gets copied to the thread function `someFunction()`. So `delete` delets the correct object.

Comment: The important thing is that the address in `d` is allocated **once** using `new` and deleted **once** using `delete`.

Comment: @Celeritas When the `d` in `doWork()` goes out of scope *nothing will happen to the object* because it was created using `new`..

Comment: If `pthread_create` fails you leak memory. Also you do not need to cast to `void*` as the conversion is implicit. Your use of C style casts is also non-idiomatic.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious thnx

Comment: @Celeritas please review the changes (especially checking pthread_create for errors).

Comment: @Galik "No because all delete cares about is the value of the pointer." so this works because the value of `d` in both `doWork()` and `someFunction()` are the same, correct?

Comment: @Celeritas Yes. The pointer is copied (its value) from `dat` to `d` but not the object it points to. So `d` points to the same object whose address was assigned to `dat`. When `doWork()` goes out of scope the pointer `dat` is destroyed but the object it pointed to lives on. Its address is now stored in `d` where it can be deleted from.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to worry about memory leak. One of the solutions is to delete `Data*` at the end of `someFunction`.

Comment: the pointer in someFunction might become corrupt even before it started to execute, if the parent thread exits earlier.

Comment: Yes, but we talk here about `Data* d = new Data();`. With this it won't corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ answer that corresponds to your code would use `<thread>`:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

struct Data { int x; int y; int z; };

void someFunction(Data const & d)
{
    std::cout << d.x << ", " << d.y << ", " << d.z << "\n";
}

void doWork()
{
    std::thread(someFunction, Data{1, 2, 3}).detach();
}
```

Both your original version and my rewrite forget the thread after creation and sort of rely on it to finish eventually, before the program exits. If you wanted to join the thread explicitly, you'd have to store the thread handle somewhere.

Writing to `std::cout` without further synchronization may also lead to unexpected results.

Comment: I think OP only interested in pre C++11 stuffs

Comment: @Celeritas: pthreads is part of the Posix standard, `<thread>` is part of the C++ standard.

Comment: @KerrekSB what I meant to ask is how does one decided whether to use pthreads vs std::thread, for example are they both intdended for the same use? Thanks.